# Не отправляется текст с формы на почту, только статический. Прошу помочь

Tags: php, html, ajax, email, форма

ВООБЩЕ НЕ ПОНИМАЮ! СТОЛЬКО ПЕРЕШАРИЛ, ВРОДЕ ПЕРЕМЕННЫЕ ПРАВИЛЬНО УКАЗАНЫ. ОЧЕНЬ ПРОШУ ПОМОЧЬ! СООБЩЕНИЕ ОТПРАВЛЯЕТСЯ, Я ПОЛУЧАЮ НА ПОЧТУ ТЕКСТ, ПРОСТО ТЕКСТ С ФОРМЫ НЕ МОГУ ПОЛУЧИТЬ!

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <form action="mail.php" method="POST">
            <legend>Заголовок формы</legend>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Введите ваше имя</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="user_name" placeholder="Например, Иван">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Введите номер телефона</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="user_phone" placeholder="+7 (999) 99 99 999">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Введите email</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="user_email" placeholder="mail@mail.ru">
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Отправить форму</button>
        </form>
    </div><!-- .col-sm-4 -->
  </div> <!-- .row -->

</div><!-- /.container -->
```

```css
//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.mail.ru';                         // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'vladobradley@mail.ru'; // Ваш логин от почты с которой будут отправляться письма
$mail->Password = 'парольмой'; // Ваш пароль от почты с которой будут отправляться письма
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 465; // TCP port to connect to / этот порт может отличаться у других провайдеров

$mail->setFrom('vladobradley@mail.ru'); // от кого будет уходить письмо?
$mail->addAddress('tekopro@mail.ru');     // Кому будет уходить письмо 
//$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
//$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
//$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
//$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');
//$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
//$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Заявка с тестового сайта';
$mail->Body    = '' .$name . ' оставил заявку, его телефон ' .$phone. '<br>Почта этого пользователя: ' .$email;
$mail->AltBody = '';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Error';
} else {
    header('location: thank-you.html');
}
?>
```

Comment: Текст: оставил заявку, его телефон.

Answer (score 0):

```
$mail->Body    = '' .$_POST["user_name"]. ' оставил заявку, его телефон ' .$_POST["user_phone"]. '<br>Почта этого пользователя: ' .$_POST["user_email"];
```

Comment: Не сработало, есть ещё варианты?

Comment: покажите полный html код в котором полностью виден тег `<form`

Comment: Изменил сообщение.

Comment: Изменил текст в вопросе, кстати код не менял почти, скачать готовый где всё работало, только у меня не работает.

Comment: Код отправки почты у вас в mail.php находится? Приходят ли туда данные с формы? ($_POST['user_name], $_POST["user_email"] и т.п)? И уберите id из полей формы, если вы его не используете

Comment: какой текст вы получаете на почту?

Comment: Текст: оставил заявку, его телефон

Comment: Да в mail.php , приходит только статический текст ,не приходят данные с формы

Comment: То есть вы заменили вашу строчку `$mail->Body    = '' .$name . ' оставил заявку, его телефон ' .$phone. '<br>Почта этого пользователя: ' .$email;` на мою из ответа и ничего не сработало?

Comment: Не сработало !!

Comment: у вас тегах к вопросу стоит метка Ajax - как отправляются данные формы?

Comment: Вообще запутался,данную систему я взял с интернета и просто закинул на хостинг.

Answer (score 0):

Пробуй вот так, замени почты и пароль

```js
<?php 

require_once('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';

$name = $_POST['user_name'];
$phone = $_POST['user_phone'];
$email = $_POST['user_email'];

$mail->isSMTP(); // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.mail.ru'; // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'email@mail.ru'; // Ваш логин от почты с которой будут отправляться письма
$mail->Password = 'password'; // Ваш пароль от почты с которой будут отправляться письма
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 465; // TCP port to connect to / этот порт может отличаться у других провайдеров

$mail->setFrom('email@mail.ru'); // от кого будет уходить письмо?
$mail->addAddress('email@mail.ru'); // Кому будет уходить письмо 
$mail->isHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Заявка с тестового сайта';
$mail->Body    = "$name оставил(-а) заявку<br/> Телефон: $phone <br/> Адрес почты: $email";
$mail->AltBody = '';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Error';
} else {
    header('location: /');
}
?>
```

```html
<form action="mail.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="user_name" placeholder="Name" required>
  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="phone" name="user_phone" placeholder="Phone" required>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="" name="user_email" placeholder="Email" required>
  <button type="submit">Поехали!</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Так же, отправляется статический текст, но не отправляется данные с формы!

Comment: @ВладиславЩукин Попробуй добавить параметр к форме `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, то есть:  
`<form action="mail.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">` или `<form action="mail.php" method="POST" enctype="text/plain">`

Comment: Всё та же проблема, не получилось.

Comment: @ВладиславЩукин у тебя ошибка наверное в самом файле mail.php.  
Побалуйся з переменными, могу скинуть свой вариант, рабочий.

Comment: давай, буду очень благодарен, но в чём прикол..
Данную форму я взял на ютюбе, где у него всё работало, у меня же не работает

Comment: @ВладиславЩукин Обновил пост.

Comment: Ёё, не работает, может ли это проблемма быть с хостингом?

Comment: @ВладиславЩукин Вполне. Но если отправляет, но только без текста в  атрибуте `value`, тогда не знаю, в чем прикол :)  
Возможно и в хостинге, попробуй другой.
К примеру, zzz.com.ua - чисто для теста. У меня там работает, на тестовом сайте

Comment: пасиб, поразбираюсь